# Confirm SQL Server Bug?

Tags: sql-server

If you run the below query in SQL Server 2014, what do you get for the result of column DT? It should be "1", but in SQL Server 2008, I'm getting "0".

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN CAST('2014-01-02 00:00:00.001' AS DATETIME) > CAST('2014-01-02 00:00:00.000' AS DATETIME) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS 'DT'
    , CASE WHEN CAST('2014-01-02 00:00:00.002' AS DATETIME) > CAST('2014-01-02 00:00:00.000' AS DATETIME) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS 'DT2'
    , CASE WHEN '2014-01-02 00:00:00.001' > '2014-01-02 00:00:00.000' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS 'VARCHAR'
```

Comment: resolution of datetime is 3.33 milliseconds

Comment: You can simplify your query, as last 2 cases are not related to your question.

Comment: The take home form this is, don't automatically assume it's a bug in SQL Server....

Comment: As of SQL Server **2008**, I would recommend to stop using `DATETIME` and instead use `DATETIME2(n)` instead. It's much more accurate (you can define the accuracy needed, down to 100ns) and it covers the date range from 1/1/0001 (instead of 1/1/1753). If you replace `DATETIME` with `DATETIME2(3)` (3 digits after the decimal point - accurate to the millisecond), your query works **as expected**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The resolution of the date time field is to **3 decimal places**. Is only accurate to **within 3.33 ms**

SQL server consider both `'2014-01-02 00:00:00.001'` and `'2014-01-02 00:00:00.000'` as `2014-01-02 00:00:00.000`.

```
SELECT Cast('2014-01-02 00:00:00.001' AS DATETIME),
       Cast('2014-01-02 00:00:00.000' AS DATETIME)
```

Result will same for both the dates.

In your case statement `CAST('2014-01-02 00:00:00.001' AS DATETIME) > CAST('2014-01-02 00:00:00.000' AS DATETIME)` has failed because both are equal so  else part `0` worked.

Comment: @MitchWheat is that enough to make someone understand?

Comment: @MitchWheat - Not a problem. I know its not your DV

Comment: I think it would be more accurate to say "The resolution of the DateTime datatype is 3.33ms" mentioning decimal places I think is slightly imprecise.

Comment: @MitchWheat and @ NoDisplayName - Thank you both, the 3.33ms I think is the key here rather than the 3 decimal place resolution.